# Redirect issue using popup authentication

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-socialite

The issue I encounter is that when I try click the login via Facebook button, a popup is shown, it authenticates, a 302 request is sent to my server and then the request sent throws an error:

`Failed to load https://www.facebook.com/v2.10/dialog/oauth?client_id=1869475260039930&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fordering.dev%2Fapi%2Flogin%2Ffacebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code&display=popup: Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`

```
Route::post('login/{provider}', 'SocialAuthController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('login/{provider}/callback', 'SocialAuthController@handleProviderCallback')->name('api-callback');
```

My Controller:

```
public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    // will get called
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->asPopup()->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    // this endpoint is never called
    return response()->json('test');

    // more logic
}
```

Frontend code:

```
socialLogin(provider) {
    console.log('social login');
    let this_ = this;
    // vue-authenticate
    this.$auth.authenticate(provider).then(function () {
       // success - never called
    }).catch(function (err) {
        // error is always thrown
        console.log('error is', err);
    });
}
```

How can I make sure that I my `handleProviderCallback($provider)` function is called and passes through the correct info?

Comment: Did you register your correct domain with Facebook? Also be careful with the .dev domain. Google has acquired it (https://iyware.com/dont-use-dev-for-development/) and recently forced all usage of .dev to the HTTPS only (which can be really annoying locally)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I got it secured, so I don't have any SSL issues, but you're right, since 63, that would happen. Anyways, it did realize that actually `handleProviderCallback($provider) ` is called, but the redirect error still occurs.

Comment: This seems like a CORS problem. Your javascript is sending something to a server. The server then sends a redirect. Instead it should set the appropriate CORS headers as well. See https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0 for the docs for example